# user vaidation / unique email using cartylyst sentinel

Tags: php, laravel, sentinel

I want to validate user using sentinel and i want to check that unique user email_address my post request looks like:

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $user = Sentinel::register($request->all());
    $activation = Activation::create($user);

    $this->sendEmail($user, $activation->code);
    return redirect()->back()->with([
        'sucess' => 'user registered successfully'
    ]);
}
```

Here i am adding first_name , last_name , email_address and password but i want to validate these fields and with unique email_address?
How i can do that?
Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
]);
```

After this, put $validateData to register

```
$user = Sentinel::register($validatedData);
```

But, for first step, i recommended use Custom request class, and put validation in rules() method. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: its not validating with sentinel users